# Peculiar problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I have a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)));
```

Now I populate it

```
DataRow dn = dt.NewRow();
dn["Country"] = "1";
dn["State"] == "2";

// Add it
dt.Rows.Add(dn);
```

That works fine. Now if Country and State are zero, I don't want it to add to the table. For example:

```
dn["Country"] = "0";
dn["State"] = "0";

if (dn["Country"].ToString() != "0" &&
    dn["State"].ToString() != "0")
   dt.Rows.Add(dn);
```

That doesn't work. What am I doing wrong there? I've tried setting type to int and that didn't help much either...

Thanks,
Jim

**Update**:

This is more like what I'm doing:

```
dn["Country"] = (from c in db.Country where c.Zone == 3 select c.Code).Count();
```

Now if that were to return Zero, the row should not be added to the DataTable. What instead happens is that if the count is greater than 0, its not added either.

**Update 2**

Got it to work with Any() for now, as suggested by Jon Skeet below. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please improve your title it's not descriptive enough!

Comment: It's pretty nasty using strings for integers and makes comparison logic messy.

Comment: Both Country and State must be more than 0 for it to add the row.

Comment: James: That is what I want it do do. It doesn't add irrespective of what the Country and State values are.

Comment: @pjp: Just an example. Same issue with integers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "that doesn't work" do you mean the row gets added anyway? That sounds very odd - do you have a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Here's a short but complete program which *does* work:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Country", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("State", typeof(string)));

        DataRow dn = dt.NewRow();
        dn["Country"] = "0";
        dn["State"] = "0";

        if (dn["Country"].ToString() != "0" &&
            dn["State"].ToString() != "0")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Broken");
            dt.Rows.Add(dn);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working");
        }
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing based on snippets, but is it possible that you're changing the values of a row which is *already* in the `DataTable`, instead of one which hasn't been added yet?

EDIT: This is a pretty strange line of code you've got:

```
dn["Country"] = (from c in db.Country where c.Zone == 3 select c.Code).Count();
```

Why would you set the *country* to a *count*? Furthermore, if you only care about the *count* why are you bothering with the projection?

Finally, I'd probably just use a local variable instead of putting it in the datarow to start with:

```
int count = db.Country.Where(c => c.Zone == 3).Count();
if (count != 0)
{
    // Use count, add the row etc
}
```

Oh, and if you don't really need the count, but just need to know whether it's non-zero, use `Any`:

```
if (db.Country.Any(c => c.Zone == 3))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is more like what I'm doing:

dn["Country"] = (from c in db.Country where c.Zone == 3 select c.Code).Count();

Now if that were to return Zero, the row should not be added to the DataTable. What instead happens is that if the count is greater than 0, its not added either.

Comment: Formatting messed up: I've updated the main post with my reply.

Comment: You haven't said whether you're reusing an existing row or creating a new one.

Comment: Jon, that was an example. I'm not sure what is going wrong but none of the methods work. The comparison fails irrespective of the count. I'll try and work on a sample. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jim: The closer your examples are to reality, the more chance we have of working out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your populate code is wrong, i don't know if this is a typo or directly from your source.

You wrote

```
//the "==" won't assign anything to the dn["State"] column
dn["State"] == "2";
```

where you actually need

```
//the "=" will
dn["State"] = "2";
```

Because the State column never gets populated your if condition won't work.

```
if (dn["Country"].ToString() != "0" 
 && dn["State"].ToString() != "0") 
//this will always be false because dn["State"] was never assigned to
```

Another point is that if the column hasn't had a value specified the value will be DBNull.  You should perhaps modify your check to also see if the values are DBNull, you can do this using the [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx) method.

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Except that *will* work with the snippet which sets them both to "0"

Comment: Good point Jon, I didn't notice the assignment in the 3rd snippet.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are assigning an `int` (that will be boxed to `object`) to the DataRow:

```
dn["Country"] = (from c in db.Country where c.Zone == 3 select c.Code).Count();
```

And then comparing it to a `string`:

```
if (dn["Country"].ToString() != "0"
```

Try changing `Count()` to `Count().ToString()` and the problem may be solved.

Comment: the .ToString() does the conversion of whatever datatype is in the dn["Country"] field anyways...

Comment: That's true; for some reason I didn't catch the .ToString() as part of the comparison.